# How is the Sub or Set to Be Understood?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to VB.NET 2012 (Visual Studio 2012).

I am wondering how is the following error message to be understood?

```
 'Return' statement in a Sub or a Set cannot return a value.
```

The focus is on "Sub or Set".

In case of interest, I am trying to have messages printed out through numerous ways.

Answer (score 6):

> How is the Sub or Set to Be Understood?

A `Sub` is a method without a return value:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    …
End Sub
```

(In contrast to a `Function`, which is a method with a return value.)

A `Set` is the setter of a property:

```
Property X() As String
    Get
        Return SomeValue
    End Get
    Set(Value As String)
        SomeValue = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Unlike property getters and functions, `Sub`s and `Set`ters don’t return a value and hence cannot contain a `Return X` statement (they *can* contain a naked `Return` which exits the method prematurely without returning a value, equivalent to `Exit Sub` or `Exit Property`).

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `Return` statement in a `Sub` or a `Set` and you're trying to return a value. You can't do that.

```
Sub Something
    Return 1 ' Error
End Sub
```

If you need  to return a value, then you need a Function:

```
Function Something As Integer
    Return 1 ' Ok
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return something in a Sub, but you can in a Function.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d03wadb1(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In a Sub you can have a Return statement, but not "with a value", i.e.:

```
Sub MySub()
  Return ' this is OK. It is optional (you do not HAVE to have a Return in a Sub).
End Sub
```

but

```
Sub MySub()
  Return 3 ' this is WRONG
End Sub
```

In a Property_SET you can have no Return statement whatsoever.
(In a Property_GET, at the other hand, you MUST have a Return statement WITH a value that conforms to the TYPE of the Property.

```
Property MyProperty() As Integer
  Get
    ' do all kinds of stuff
    Return 3 ' Returns as integer-type value
  End Get
  Set(value as Integer)
    ' do stuff
    Return ' WRONG
    Return 3 ' also WRONG
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: `Set` *can* contain a `Return` statement and it’s equivalent to `Exit Property`.